# How to play MKV videos in Mozilla FIrefox?

Tags: firefox, video, mkv

I can't play or stream online videos with MKV extesions in Firefox though I can play these videos through Chrome.
It says "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported." while trying to play the video.

I am Using the latest Firefox for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you give a site that has those mkv videos?

Comment: MKV files are meant to be watched locally, not through your web browser.

Comment: @mmstick But Chrome can play them so I thought there is a way to play them through Firefox.

Comment: No, it's not officially supported by any web browswer: https://caniuse.com/#search=mkv MP4, on the other hand, is supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4

Comment: `MKV files are meant to be watched locally, not through your web browser.` @mmstick: that's not true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately its simply not supported.

There is bug on Mozilla's Bugzilla - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422891 but without much of progress here.

Answer (score 0):

.Mkv and/or other video files can be played through firefox and firefox mobile by either right-click/long-press on video link for play options then choose the video player you know sorts the file example VLC player on Android market.